# How to Avoid Overlapping text in <DIV> tag & to set the Height of <Div> tag automatically if Text in <DIV> is more?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

i have a **DIV** tag in Repeater control of asp.net. When their is less text then it displays well. But, When the **Text in DIV increases then it has to get AutoAdjusted in DIV**. But, it Overlaps with its next row of DIV in Repeater Control.

How to set it so that it should get Self Adjust Height in DIV?

In Style.css File:

```
.UserControlDiv
{ 
    height: 45px;     
    float: left;  
}

 <div style="width:380px;" class="UserControlDiv">
                <%# Eval("Address")%>
 </div>
 <div style="width:380px;" class="UserControlDiv">
                <%# Eval("UnicodeAddress")%>
 </div>
```

With above CSS the Text in Address get overlapped with the next row.
Help Appreciated!

Comment: try by `padding-bottom: 45px;` instead of `height: 45px;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using "min-height":

```
.UserControlDiv
{ 
    min-height: 45px;     
    float: left;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need separate row for each 2 divs you can wrap template into another div.

```
<style>
.row
{
    clear:both;
    min-height:45px;    
}

.UserControlDiv
{     
    float: left;  
}
</style>

<div class='row'>
    <div style="width:380px;" class="UserControlDiv">
                  <%# Eval("Address")%>

    </div>
    <div style="width:380px;" class="UserControlDiv">
                   <%# Eval("UnicodeAddress")%>
    </div>
</div>
```